# Do heavenly beings possession genitals? Genesis 6:4

Tags: psalms, pneumatology, angels, body

> “And David took more wives in Jerusalem, and David **fathered more sons and daughters**.”
> ‭‭1 Chronicles‬ ‭14:3‬ ‭

> “Then Abraham prayed to God, and God healed Abimelech, and also healed his wife and female slaves **so that they bore children**.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭20:17‬ ‭

Could we agree that these two bolded text would indicate that both David and Abimelech had genitals?

Now consider

> “the sons of God came in to the daughters of man and **they bore children** to them. These were the mighty men who were of old, the men of renown.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:4‬ ‭

Could we not infer that these heavenly beings also had genitals?

Or are we going to claim it’s opinion based answers and that it’s debatable that David even had genitalia because it’s never discussed in the pages of the Bible?

The Bible might be discreet about certain topics like “to uncover your father’s, uncle’s, brother’s nakedness” is the same as saying to sleep with his wife, yet even though it’s not explicitly spelled out, it’s is understood and not opinion based what is meant when the Bible says, to expose their nakedness.

———

> “the **sons of God** came in to the daughters of man and they bore children to them. These were the mighty men who were of old, the men of renown.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:4‬ ‭

No where in all of the OT are sons of God referred to as humans, except in translated text, as an (mis)interpretation. The Seth-ite 2nd century AD theory is not based on Scripture but a theological objection to the text of scripture popularized by Augustine in the 4th century AD. You are welcome to your opinions but until the first century that interpretation didn’t even exist.

The sons of God or the heavenly beings raped human women. Do they therefore not have genitals? And therefore have gametes(sperm)?

> “Yet you have made him (man) a little lower than the heavenly beings and crowned him with glory and honor.”
> ‭‭Psalm‬ ‭8:5‬ ‭

By inference heavenly beings must therefore be a little higher than humans.

Considering that there are only two categories of bodies

> “There are **heavenly** bodies and **earthly** bodies,”
> ‭‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15:40‬ ‭

... considering the heavenly beings have heavenly bodies, if psalm 8 verse 5 is to apply to heavenly beings, it would follow that the heavenly beings are a little higher than humans.

Would it not stand to reason that having a heavenly body means to have at least what a human/animal/earthly body has and a little more? All (higher) earthly bodies have genitals.

Heavenly beings are described both in OT and NT as men like in appearance. They are also able to interact with the natural world, i.e. Peter was struck physically in the side when woken up. So they don’t need an earthly body to interact with the natural world, because their supernatural bodies can interact with the natural world but are also super(above) the laws of nature.

Genitals/gonads are not exclusively for procreation, they also provide other functions in the body, some of which are critical for hormonal balance.

Is it therefore plausible or implausible that a heavenly being who is a little higher than man, that they should also have genitals and the ability or the equipment to procreate, even if God never created a female counterpart for them like He did for Adam?

Comment: Aren't the "heavenly bodies" just the sun, moon, and stars as verse 41 says? Paul isn't talking about heavenly beings. In any case, you're asking a topical question that isn't primarily about either verse you quoted, which makes this off-topic.

Comment: @curiousdannii *“The first man was from the earth, a man of dust; the second **man is from heaven**. As was the man of dust, so also are those who are of the dust, and as is the **man of heaven**, so also are those **who are of heaven**. Just as we have borne the image of the man of dust, we shall also bear the **image of the man of heaven**.” 1 Cor15:47-49‬* “No” this is not talking about the sun moon and stars, they were merely used to illustrate a point of comparing glory. Yes it is talking about sun, moon stars they thought stars were beings/watchers in the Bible not gas balls. Context
‭‭

Comment: This is about the text in Psalm 8:5, it claims heavenly beings (see Job 38:7 singing...) heavenly beings with heavenly bodies are higher just by a little than humans. And everywhere where these heavenly MESSENGERS, or angels/aggelos are portrayed in the Bible they are portrayed as human men. If they look like humans and Genesis 6 says they had children with human women, then why can’t we explore their anatomy? Want me to switch to Genesis 6:4? That’s speaking exactly about procreation, or Genesis 3:15 that’s speaking exactly about seed/gametes, offsprings and procreation?

Comment: Genesis 6:4 is indeed a much more relevant verse.

Comment: I really don't see any way to bring this on-topic, when it's never discussed in the pages of scripture. Even when you phrase it as a genuine hermeneutical question, the answer seems to be "the text does not mention it" - surely this can only be opinion based?

Comment: Note that many, perhaps a majority, of interpreters of Genesis 6 do not consider the "sons of God" in that verse to refer to angels/demons/heavenly beings. Some do, but if you want to direct a question directly to them, it would probably be better to ask that question at [christianity.se].

Comment: The majority of interpreters are post 1st century. In other words irrelevant to what the first century and prior believed.

Answer (score 2):

#### *Do heavenly beings possess genitals?*

Answer: **This is extremely unlikely**.

Perhaps we first need to understand the profound distinction between the majesty and perfection of the spirit realm versus the flawed, carnal, often despicable nature of the physical world in which we live. If we are unable to do this, we may be hopelessly adrift in our recognition of certain spiritual realities. Let us read a passage from the First Letter to the Corinthians:

> **1 Corinthians 2:9**: "[Just] as it is written, 'THINGS WHICH EYE HAS NOT SEEN AND EAR HAS NOT HEARD, AND *which HAVE NOT ENTERED THE HEART OF MAN, ALL THAT GOD HAS PREPARED FOR THOSE WHO LOVE HIM*'" (emphasis added, caps in the original, NASB).

Does this sound like God has prepared *yet another* Earth prone to fall? Will we possess the knowledge of good and evil in paradise? If so, how could we ever stand before God with deceitful or lustful thoughts in our minds without immediately being banished from heaven?

And, why stop at reproductive organs? Should we expect filthy toilets as well as vast waste disposal systems in paradise, along with raw sewage plants? Would a host of other abominations be the order of the day in the paradise of God?

We should all immediately understand that these things — and many, many more — are those we have all witnessed. Our *ears have heard of them*, *our eyes have seen them*, and *they have entered our hearts and minds*."

Is this not directly contrary to everything that God has promised in the afterlife? Do we really believe we can simply anthropomorphize our spiritual existence in heaven as though it will be another worldly existence? Just what sort of view of the heavenly realm are we imagining?

No. The world in which we live is **unsalvageable**. It is terribly fallen — in every conceivable manner. We simply do not regularly stop to recognize this fact. But as we age, such things should become more apparent. The evening news stands as a constant reminder of the horrors that many experience daily all over the globe.

On the other hand, we have never witnessed the grandeur of the Garden of Eden or the life that God initially created. However, since the Fall:

> **Romans 8:22**: "[We] know that **the whole creation groans and suffers the pains of childbirth together until now**."

If someone staunchly believes that "Life is beautiful!", they need to carefully reflect on that view. Do we simply dismiss passages like the one above, instead preferring to believe that all is well on earth when it obviously is not?

Now, let us consider the OP in this regard. Isn't it just possible that heaven will consist of a celestial, angelic host that is absolutely WITHOUT sin? We know that God created the angels as his ministering spirits to perform His will (Heb. 1:14).

Therefore, does it make any sense whatsoever that angels would be free to commit vile acts that are forbidden to human beings? In the absence of marriage, this might constitute unisexual fornications — perhaps even hermaphroditism. Where do you suppose that would all end? Once we become superhuman beings just as the angels, would the question from the OP not inevitably lead to heinous behavior? Would God ever tolerate such things?

Suppose we review Psalm 8:

> **Psalm 8:5**: "Yet You have made him a little lower than God, And You crown him with glory and majesty!"

Note that this passage does not indicate the degree to which we were "made lower than God." Are we capable of speaking an entire material universe into existence?

Now picture the nature of the world due to sin and human frailty. Does that begin to describe the spectacular paradise that awaits all saints? Is that really how we see the perfection and holiness of God?

Or is that how we *envision* the circumstances from a purely *human perspective*? Is this not a view being *transplanted into into the sublime grandeur of the spiritual realm* ruled by the Almighty by those who appear oblivious to the many truths that God has spoken in His Word?

**No, angels do not have such appendages. If God needs more angels, all he has to do is create them, just as He did from the beginning**.

We must never believe for a moment that heaven will be anything remotely similar to life on earth where degeneracy and godlessness run amok.

Comment: Are you suggesting that whilst Adam was in Eden he didn’t need to use the “restroom”? You realize there is eating in the new kingdom which will be on the new earth right? Are you suggesting there’s no defecation? Just ingestion? The children of israel ate the food of ‘angels’ did they not use the bathroom? A heavenly body though not confined to the natural laws is still a body.

Comment: Not having the need (according to your logic) does not constitute reason enough in my mind for lacking the equipment/genitals. Adam had genitals surely before he had Eve. But before Eve there was NO REASON... actually there were reasons because genitals are not single function. Same applies to heavenly beings, if they have genitals it’s not exclusively for one function. Why do you assume genitals are exclusively for procreation when they are not. Lips are not exclusively for kissing. So to illustrate your  example ‘angels’ don’t have lips because they don’t French kiss?? What?

Comment: @Nihil No, Adam and Eve probably did have to eliminate waste because they *were* human. But I'd suggest that consuming nutrition in heaven may be expelled through the skin (as it were), to immediately be recycled as pure. We know nothing of the anatomy of angels, but I'd like to also suggest that God has perfected spiritual bodies. They can't possibly consist of the same design as humans. You have to remember that the Israelites may have eaten manna, but that still had to be digested by *physical bodies* something we'll never possess in heaven. We must recognize the spiritual vs. the physical.

Comment: @Nihil I would just add that "kissing" is a human act that can lead to sex. I believe you are erroneously assuming *that God created angels as sexual beings*. Luke 20:35, I believe, is saying more than it is letting on: there is no marriage because there are no sexual relations in paradise. To believe there is, is to bring worldly, human baggage into heaven to suit the needs of our physical minds and bodies. Further, if sex exists outside marriage in heaven, how is that not fornication - irrespective of superior organs to do so? Are we to believe that non-sexual beings are driven to multiply?

Comment: I get the sense that spiritual to you is esoteric. *“I tell you I will not drink again of **this fruit** of the vine until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father’s kingdom.””
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭26:29‬* spiritual bodies drinking physical drinks. If that makes sense to you why does it make sense? Is it because spiritual bodies have physical properties but are not limited to the laws of the natural physical realm? Why don’t these bodies require elimination or why is it more acceptable to eliminate through the epithelium rather than the urethra? ‘Angels’ are only a **little** higher than man

Comment: That’s my point Xeno, having genitals doesn’t equal sexual acts. But you’re saying since there is no sexual acts in Heaven because there is no marriage then genitals serve no purpose, so therefore ‘angels’ don’t need genitals and most likely don’t have genitals. That’s fallacious. Genitals are not used exclusively for sex. And Heaven is not a sin-proof zone, Lucifer was able to sin. And we won’t be in Heaven but in the kingdom of Heaven which is on the new earth with gardens and fruits and a wedding banquet and bodies like Jesus’ who are fish and honey

Comment: @Nihil How do we know when Christ ascended into heaven, the fruit of which He speaks is the exact fruit of the vine that exists on earth. You seem intent on physicalizing the spiritual realm - something about which we know very little. You are right: I do not think there are toilets in heaven. I also don't think there are landfills, or purification plants. Can God Himself do none of these things? Does the word "omnipotent" have no meaning? For me, it means that the spiritual realm is so beyond our imagination that we can even fathom at all what it will be like. None of this has to do with sex.

Comment: Thank you for your response though

Comment: @Nihil Perhaps you don't now this, but I am an amillennialist. And, there is no doubt in my mind that heaven is a realm of absolute holiness, perfection, and grandeur. So we disagree on more that I can communicate here. The question is NOT whether angels have genitals. The question is whether heaven, or paradise, or whatever you like, is exactly the same as this world. **1 Cor. 2:9** tells us it is not, and that no one has imagined what it will be. I think that speaks for itself. "Lucifer" is Jerome's xlation of "morning star" - Venus. Rev. 22:16 calls Christ the "bright morning star."

Comment: You have to admit that 1Cor2:9 does not confirm nor deny that these things have or lack physicality. You cannot make that point based on this verse. It merely says that they are unfathomable to the human mind and nothing like it existed on earth at that time. Something unimaginable does not also mean lacks physicality. Nature groans and awaits redemption, redemption means to bring back to original state. Nature is physical, it always has been. When nature is redeemed it will still be physical

Comment: @Nihil There is a site that has helped me a great deal over these past 8 years or so as a Christian. It is [ChristianCourier.com](https://www.christiancourier.com/articles/1353-will-heaven-be-on-earth). There is a good article on the "new earth" that might interest you. I realize you may disagree with it, but it is a very good source on many biblical matters.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can ask whatever they want. But to better relate; id like at least some rational for asking them.

There are somethings that come to mind at least:

1* Jesus taught theres no giving and taking in marriage relating to women.

There's no giving and taking in marriage male female relations; all are as the angels in heaven..

> Luke 20:34-36
>
> 34 And Jesus answering said unto them, The children of this world
> marry, and are given in marriage:
>
> 35 But they which shall be accounted worthy to obtain that world, and
> the resurrection from the dead, neither marry, nor are given in
> marriage:
>
> 36 Neither can they die any more: for they are equal unto the angels;
> and are the children of God, being the children of the resurrection.

2* However Genesis 1 states we are made in the image of the angles.
(All times angelic beings appears and it was not a vision they appear as men)

> Jude 1:
>
> 6 And the angels which kept not their first estate, but left their own
> habitation, he hath reserved in everlasting chains under darkness unto
> the judgment of the great day.
>
> 7 Even as Sodom and Gomorrha, and the cities about them in like
> manner, giving themselves over to fornication, and going after strange
> flesh, are set forth for an example, suffering the vengeance of
> eternal fire.

Genesis 6 and Jude lets us know, they were able to impregnate women.
This resulted with the giants recorded throughout Israels History when taking over the lands allotted to them.

> Genesis 6:2-4 (kjv)
>
> 2 That the sons of God saw the daughters of men that they were fair;
> and they took them wives of all which they chose.
>
> 3 And the Lord said, My spirit shall not always strive with man, for
> that he also is flesh: yet his days shall be an hundred and twenty
> years.
>
> 4 There were giants in the earth in those days; and also after that,
> when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men, and they bare
> children to them, the same became mighty men which were of old, men of
> renown.

Comment: "However Genesis 1 states we are made in the image of the angles" Huh? Where do you get this idea from?

Comment: @curiousdannii  While I also disagree with W_R on this point, his idea technically has Biblical support.  "Elohim" can be angels.  Check the Hebrew for Psalm 8:5 where it says we are created a little lower than the "angels"...the word there is "Elohim."  Then look at Gen. 1:26--again, it is Elohim who speaks regarding creating man in His image.  To the Hebrew mind, "Elohim" references any supernatural or heavenly being--as one of my Jewish Hebrew professors made a special point of teaching us in an online seminar we had.

Comment: @Polyhat Ahh okay, I can see where that idea fits in. But Ps 8:5 is very disputed, and lots of translations say "a little lower than God". There are other verses, but they're rare, and the non-God sense of elohim might be distinguishable by context. In any case, it's far from established that Genesis 1 has that sense!

Comment: @curiousdannii .  Polyhat basically answered this for me. 
Our image, uses the term Elohim . While people throw in trinity into this passage I don't.   John 3 Jesus explains we all come from God.  As Christ is the express image of God, so the children are in their own image as they were created from before, being born from above, to participate in salvation. Not as the fallen angels who rather than be born of women took them to wife.